# Create a mongoid field that can't be modified after the object is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I looked around but I don't see a good way to do this.  If I define a field in Mongoid, how do I make it so that it can't be modified after the first save?

I.e.

```
field :my_field, type: String, default: -> { "some computed value that I want to be immutable" }
```

Comment: default value in mongoid isn't saved in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way in the base mongoid package.

Looks like someone has published a gem to add that capability, but it doesn't look very well-used.
https://github.com/jeffbozek/mongoid_immutable_fields